# Why do I get an error in my ifstream object declaration?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm getting an error at the line that declares an `ifstream` object like this:

```
ifstream input;
```

or

```
ifstream input("somefile");
```

This will work fine the first time, but a runtime error will occur at the line above the next time through a loop!

Here is the full program source code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
#include<ctype.h>
class SV
  {
     private:
     char Name[30];
     char Gender[7]; //Try setting the bound of this array to 3 and see what will happen to the value of GioiTinh whenever we assign a string to it
     char BirthDay[10];
     char HomeTown[40];
     char CurrentLocation[40];
     char SchoolYear[5];
     char Course[20];
     char Qualification[10];
     float AverageMark;
     SV * next;

     public:
      int Nhap()
      {
            char * info[9];
            int i;
            SV * newSV = new SV;
            SV * q = new SV;
            strcpy(Name, "");
//-----------------------
            for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
              info[i] = new char[50];
            i = 0;
            ifstream input("Student.INP"); // <--- I'm stuck here
            if(input.bad())
              {
                 cout<<endl<<"The file \"Student.INP\" doesn't exist in the folder of the program!!!";
                 return -1;
              }
            do
            {
              char s[255];
              i = 0;
              input.getline(s,255);
              int j = 0;
              int k = 0;
              do
              {
                 if(s[j] == '\0')
                    {
                      info[i][k] = '\0';
                      break;
                    }
                 if(s[j] == '|')
                    {
                      info[i][k] = '\0';
                      k = 0;
                      i++;
                      j++;
                      continue;
                    }
                 info[i][k] =  s[j];
                 k++;
                 j++;
              }while(j < 255);
            strcpy(newSV->Name,info[0]);
            strcpy(newSV->Gender,info[1]);
            strcpy(newSV->BirthDay,info[2]);
            strcpy(newSV->HomeTown , info[3]);
            strcpy(newSV->CurrentLocation,info[4]);
            strcpy(newSV->SchoolYear,info[5]);
            strcpy(newSV->Course,info[6]);
            strcpy(newSV->Qualification,info[7]);
            newSV->AverageMark = atof(info[8]);
            newSV->next = NULL;
            if(strcmp(Name, "") == 0)
            {
                 *this = *newSV;
                 next = q;
            }
            else
            {
                *q = *newSV;
                if(!input.eof())
                  {
                    q->next = new SV;
                    q = q->next;
                  }
                else
                 {
                    q->next = NULL;
                    delete q;
                    break;
                 }
            }

            }while(1);
            input.close();
            delete info;
            delete newSV;
            return 0;
      }
//There are more functions ...
  };
//The main entry point of the program
void main()
{
  do
    {
     QLSV();
     cout<<endl<<"Press any key to continue ...";
     getch(); 
    }while(1);

}
```

The following links may help:

1. [Borland Turbo C++ 4.5](http://www.mediafire.com/?37jh8jqt5u5q1z5)
2. [Full source code](https://sites.google.com/site/esubstance/home/miscellaneous-notes/download-some-utilities/QLSV.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

If I use a FILE pointer instead (C) of an ifstream (C++), I can run the program "longer", but sometimes the error also points to `FILE * f = fopen("somefile", "r");`.

Comment: This is *far* too much code for anyone to read here.  Please reduce your program to the *minimum* possible that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Actually, please edit your *original* question and add the minimised code there.  I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with ifstream object declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845565/error-with-ifstream-object-declaration)

Comment: Hey, Please, It you have to delete one of them, please delete the older I posted, that doesn't contain any codes

Comment: @King Boy: Just edit *that* one!

Comment: How are you getting a "runtime error" that points to a line of your .cpp file? ... There is no runtime here other than the OS, so with a C++ file that typically means a crash with an associated error report from the OS itself, an infinite loop that locks the program up, or just incorrect output ... unless you've created some code to trigger an error report by the program itself, I don't see how you're isolating the error to that line of code.  Are you getting this error when running in a debugger?  Or are you actually getting a compile-time error? What is the exact error reporting?

Comment: We don't know what Borland believed this should do, as the compiler is several years older than the ISO C++ standard. Support for the product ended about 15 years ago!

Comment: The header file `<fstream.h>` has long been deprecated in favor of the header `<fstream>`.  I would strongly suggest updating your compiler and writing standard-compliant C++ code.

Comment: Why no use of `std::string` and `std::getline`... this could simplify a number of parts in your code.